# How to set defined values for a parameter in C#?

Tags: c#

How can I set defined values for a parameter? I mean, for example, I have the following function:

```
int functionA(string parameterA) {}
```

Now, when I call this function and input value for the parameterA, I want the value to be in the value set I have defined. For example, the defined value set is:

```
string[] definedParameterA = { "Hello World", "stackoverflow" };
```

the value of parameterA I input must be "Hello World" or "stackoverflow".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want it to be a string, you'd just validate it at the start of the method:

```
private static readonly String[] ValidValues = {"Hello World", "stackoverflow"};

public void DoSomething(string text)
{
    if (!ValidValues.Contains(text))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid value: " + text, "text");
    }
    // Carry on
}
```

However, you might also consider using an enum instead. You still need to validate that the enum value is defined, but it makes it simpler for the caller to get it right:

```
public enum Message
{
    HelloWorld,
    StackOverflow
}

public void DoSomething(Message message)
{
    if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Enum), message))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid value: " + message, "message");
    }
    // Carry on
}
```

You can have a mapping from the enum value to string elsewhere if you want, of course.

Note that the above code will box `message` on every call. You could avoid that (and make it more typesafe) using my [Unconstrained Melody](https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) project if you *really* want, but it's probably not worth it until you've proved that this boxing is actually an issue. The code would then look like this:

```
public void DoSomething(Message message)
{
    if (!message.IsNamedValue()) // Extension method
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid value: " + message, "message");
    }
    // Carry on
}
```

Comment: `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is also a possible type to throw.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Yes, I considered that. Probably more appropriate for the enum version than the string version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a static class helps you.

```
public static class MyValidParameters
{
    public static const string HelloWorld = "Hello World";
    public static const string Stackoverflow = "stackoverflow";
    //
}
```

So you can have complex parameters (not only string) of any type and you can manage them in different static classes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to rephrase John Skeet's answer in most general terms:

You're using a string. A string is an unbounded type that can contain a practically unlimited spectrum of possible values, from `null` to `""` to the complete works of Shakespeare. If you're only expecting a handful of possible values, perhaps an unbounded data type isn't the right choice for you. Perhaps you can replace it with a bounded data type instead?

As John Skeet shows, the simplest bounded data type built into the system is Enums. They provide a closed set of possible values. So you get your input, map it into the list of values, and use that from now on. However, there are some complications. The first is the possible perfomance penalty that John Skeet mentioned. The second is that not all strings can be represented as Enum values. "Hello World", for instance, is not a valid C# identifier, and thus it'll be hard to map it into an enum.

This can be done by decorating the enum value with a `[Description("Hello world")]` or `[DisplayName("Hello world")]` attribute and use reflection to match it, but that has its own performance penalties. In this case, you might consider having some sort of static utility to map a string to an enum value.